# confusion of differentiability of function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional manifold, $N$ be a finite-dimensional sub-manifold of the separable Hilbert space $L^2([0,T],\mathbb{R})$, $$
\Phi:M\to N
$$ be a diffeomorphism and 
$$
F:L^2([0,T],\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}
$$ 
be a continuously Frechet differentiable functional.

Then I the map $F|_{N}\circ \Phi:M\to \mathbb{R}$ should be differentiable but how can I compute
$$
d(F|_{N}\circ \Phi)?
$$
It seems to me that $d\Phi d(F|_{N})(\Phi)$ clearly makes no sense.  Excuse me if this question is silly.

Comment: Intuitively I would say $dF|_\Phi \circ \Phi_*$ where $\Phi_*$ is the push-forward. I say that because $d(F\circ \Phi) = d(\Phi^*F) = \Phi^*(dF) = dF|_\Phi \circ \Phi_*$ where $\Phi^*$ is the pull-back.

Comment: That sounds reasonable... could you make that more rigorous for me and I'll accept the answer

Comment: Using local coordinates $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^m \to M, \psi :\mathbb{R}^n \to N, g(x)= \psi^{-1} \circ \Phi \circ \varphi(x), f(y) = F \circ \psi(y) $ it reduces to : if $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m, f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^k$ are differentiable then $$g(x+v) = g(x)+ T_x v + o(\|v\|), \qquad f(y+u) = f(y)+ S_y u + o(\|u\|), \\ f(g(x+v)) = f(g(x)+ T_x v + o(\|v\|)) = f(g(x))+ S_{g(x)} T_x v+ o(\|v\|))$$
where $T_x,S_y$ are linear maps : the Frechet derivatives at $x,y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is
$$d(F\circ\Phi) = (dF)|_\Phi \circ \Phi_*$$
where $\Phi_* : TM \rightarrow TN$ is the push-forward. A quick proof would be a sequence of three equalities
$$d(F\circ \Phi) = d(\Phi^*F) = \Phi^*(dF) = (dF)|_\Phi \circ \Phi_*$$
where $\Phi^* : T^*N \rightarrow T^*M$ is the pull-back. Here I claimed three equalities. The first is just definition of pull-back so it's true. The last is also just definition of pull-back of forms so it's true. The tricky one here is the equality in the middle, i.e. that the pull-back commutes with the exterior derivative (in finite dimensions this is true, but in infinite dimensions ?). Nonetheless it's still true. $dF|_N$ is a 1-form over a finite dimensional manifold. So, a more rigorous proof would be :
$$d(F\circ \Phi) \\= d(F|_N\circ \Phi) 
\\= d(\Phi^*(F|_N)) 
\\= \Phi^*(d(F|_N)) 
\\= \Phi^*((dF)|_{TN}) 
\\= (dF)|_{TN} \circ \Phi_*
\\= dF \circ \Phi_*$$
What I did is simply get back to the finite dimensional case.
$$M \xrightarrow{\Phi} N \xrightarrow{F|_N}\mathbb{R}$$
$$TM \xrightarrow{\Phi_*} TN \xrightarrow{(dF)|_{TN}}\mathbb{R}$$